# How to create nested array in laravel sessions?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying to set nested array in sessions using laravel methods.

So i need to get something like this

```
$_SESSION['order'][$productId] = array();
```

Is it possible to do with laravel built-in methods?

Comment: Check the docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data

Answer (score 1):

There is a little dirty way of achieving this:

```
$sessionData = Session->get('parentKey')
```

Than do some processing of data and add nested data to it, then do:

```
Session->put('parentKey', $sessionData)
```

I hope it is helpful for you.